# Debugging and seeing where I am in the code without setting breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure if there is a term for this or if there is a feature or 3rd party add-in. Basically, I would like Visual Studio to show me where I am in my code as I am debugging and playing with my program. For example, if I am debugging and I click on Button1, I would like to see the last thing executed in that Button1's code.

Is this possible with visual studio or a 3rd party add-on?

Comment: That's exactly what breakpoints are for - stoppiing execution at a specific point in the code and allowing you to step through from there. If you tant to click on Button1 and see the last thing executed in Button1's code, set a breakpoint on the last line in Button1's code. Why do you not find that suitable?

Comment: I don't want the program to stop, that's the only reason why. I want to see it go through instead of stopping at a certain point

Comment: That makes no sense. How can is possible to see where you are in the code while it's running without stopping? You can set the breakpoint and then step through from that point. If you want ti not to stop, you can't see where you are at all.

Comment: "I would like to see the last thing executed in that Button1's code." What's that exactly? An example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to see a methods chain executed when you click a button.